# Can we delete the one-time used compiler after installation in centos?

Tags: linux, centos

I am using Centos 6.5, has gcc 4.72 as default.
One R package installation need gcc 4.92 compiler, then I `yum install devtoolset-3` and `scl enable devtoolset-3 bash` to make the installation successfully finished.
As devtoolset-3 is only used for this time R package installation, can I delete it (`yum remove devtoolset-3`)after installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, yes. There is a very small chance that your R package needs the compiler to run to do whatever when it has some C interface, but then you will notice it doesn't work and it should be noted in the documentation anyway.